# Regular expression for different date formats

Tags: c#, regex

Anyone know the regular expression for 6 May 2008 date format, the date will change but the format will stay the same. Thanks

Comment: What are other date formats? What have you tried so far exactly and how they don't work? Why don't you wanna use parsing them to `DateTime` instead of regex?

Comment: string pattern = "6 May 2008"

Comment: Pretty new to regex, the date is in a string eg:    1. Original Deed of Rectification dated 6 May 2008 between (1) John Smith and BobbyShevlin and (2) John Timmy. So all i want to do is extract out the date. Will always be in that format. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to `C#` — it seems to be a regex question, relevant for regex usage in any language. Removing the tag.

Comment: The dates can obviously change

Comment: try this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-date-string-in-ddMMyyyy-format-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @golergka please **never** do that! Regex questions **always** need a language/tool tag so we know which **flavor** to use. People get bashed here when posting questions only with the [regex] tag, so don't remove the additional tags :-)

Comment: @golergka At max it could be changed from C# to .NET (because Regex is a .NET class), but I do feel that the language tag is better, because in this way we can write some lines of code example

Comment: Again the date will change xanatos and beresfordt

Comment: If you want change date format, you can use this: datetimeValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: This is an example on how a bad choice of demo data can throw people to the wrong answer. since dd MMM yyyy is such a common format, I didn't even think about using the hole month name, but jumped straight to the assumption that it's a 3 letter abbreviation.  If the OP would have given 6 Apr 2008 or 9 Oct 2008 it would be a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern is pretty simple but cumbersome to write...

```
\d{1,2}\s+(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d{4}
```

- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\s+` - at least one space
- `(?:January|`...`|December)` - a month name (obviously)
- `\s+` at least one space
- `\d{4}` - four digits

I didn't attempt to perform any validation, so it will match `42 February 5678` - validate the date with proper tools after the match.

Comment: Tested this and it worked, i had to remove the ? though, it said it was invalid, it worked then. Thanks a million, Thanks for the explanation too!!

Comment: @user3546502 don't remove the `?`, try to remove the `i` instead: `(?:January` because `(:January` doesn't have the same meaning (it willrequire a colon before *January* to be present in the text. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need a pattern like `@"(\d{1,2} [a-z]{3} \d{4})"`.
Set the ignore case flag to true and you are good to go:

```
string s = "Original Deed of Rectification dated 6 May 2008 between (1) John Smith and BobbyShevlin and (2) John Timmy.";
Match m = new Regex(@"(\d{1,2} [a-z]{3} \d{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(s);
MessageBox.Show("|" + m.Value + "|");
```

Unless, of course, the date contains the hole month name and in that case you need [Lucas Trzesniewski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729304/3094533)
**Note:** this is not a validation in any way! just a means to extract the string that might represent a date. it will except even `43 hte 6453` as a match.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple:

```
string str = "1.    Original Deed of Rectification dated 06 May 2008 between (1) John Smith and BobbyShevlin and (2) John Timmy";

var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var monthNames = "(" + string.Join("|", culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Take(12).Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))) + ")";

var regex = new Regex("([0-3]?[1-9] " + monthNames + " [1-2][0-9]{3})");
var match = regex.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{
    string date = match.Value;
    DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d MMM yyyy", culture);
}
```

The only complex thing is how I get the month names from the .NET system. Note that the date range checking could be improved... As is it will accept *39 May 2999*, and then it will "explode" in the `DateTime.ParseExact`. Note that I'm using **abbreviated** month names :-) Jan, Feb, March and so on.